# Hide all elements but one that is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There have been some posts on this and I have gone through them but still on able to get this done. Also I am not sure what I am sure is the optimized way of doing this. Here is the html markup:

```
<nav id="main-nav">
  <ul class="main-nav-level1">
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img class="abc-logo" src="images/abc-Logo.png" alt="abc logo" title="abc logo" /></a>
    </li>
    <li class="vehicles level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Vehicles</a></li>
    <li class="shop level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Shop</a></li>
    <li class="finance level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Finance</a></li>
    <li class="owner level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Owner</a></li>
    <li class="locate-dealer-link level1">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img class="signin-avatar" src="images/mobile_locate_icon.PNG" alt="locate a dealer" title="locate a dealer" />Locate a dealer</a>
    </li>
    <li class="level1">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img class="signin-avatar" src="images/icon-search.png" alt="Search" title="Search" /></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="second-level-vehicles level1-child">
    <ul class="second-level-vehicles-nav">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Popular</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Cars</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">SUV &amp; Crossovers</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Trucks &amp; Vans</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Commercial Vehicles</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Future Vehicles</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table class="second-level-shop level1-child" cellpadding="15">
      <tr>
        <th>Research</th>
        <th>Shop</th>
        <th>Buy</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Build &amp; Price</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Search Dealer Inventory</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Request a Quote</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Help me Choose</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Special Offers</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Estimate your Payment</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Brochures and Guides</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Schedule a Test Drive</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Trade-in Value</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Get Updates</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Certified Pre-Owned</a></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="second-level-finance level1-child" cellpadding="15">
      <tr>
        <th>abc Credit Financing</th>
        <th>Tools &amp; Support</th>
        <th>Applying for Credit Card</th>
        <th>Account Management</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Financing</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Payment Calculator</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Apply Online</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">My Account</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Financing Options</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Shopping Guide</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Applying at a Dealer</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Registration</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Finance Options Tool</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Customer Support</a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Lease End Information</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">How to Pay</a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Vehicle Protection</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact Us</a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Commercial Financing</a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Special Programs</a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="second-level-owner level1-child" cellpadding="15">
      <tr>
        <th>Your Vehicle</th>
        <th>Service &amp; Maintenance</th>
        <th>Sync &amp; How-TOS</th>
        <th>Contact Us</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Owner Home</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Schedule Service</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">SYNC Technology</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Locate a Dealer</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Owner Manuals</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Service Coupons &amp; Offers</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Vehicle How-Tos</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Give Us A Call</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Your Warranty</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Redeem a Rebate</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Software Downloads</a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Roadside Assistance</a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Solution Finder</a></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</nav>
```

So here is what I am looking for. When I click on the class level1 on line 4, the class level1-child on line 10 should toggle open and if there are any other elements open they should be closed. Similarly, when I click on class level1 on line 5, the class level1-child on 21 should toggle open and all elements should be closed.

The real HTML markup will contain many other tables as shown below so I can't afford to hard code the class names in the javascript. I want to have a more generic solution. Here is the Javascript but right now I when I click on an element I am able to toggle one but not able to hide rest. Hope I am making sense.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".vehicles").click(function() {
    $(".second-level-vehicles").slideToggle("slow");
  });
  $(".shop").click(function() {
    $(".second-level-shop").slideToggle("slow");
  });
  $(".finance").click(function() {
    $(".second-level-finance").slideToggle("slow");
  });
  $(".owner").click(function() {
    $(".second-level-owner").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

As shown the above JS is not optimized. I want to avoid or at least minimize the class names hardcoded in the JS.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can pass multiple class selectors and then use it to find the corresponding class needed to toggle the corresponding section.

```
 $().ready(function(){
  $(".vehicles,.shop,.finance,.owner").click(function(){
    var this_class = $(this).attr("class").split(' ')[0];
    $('[class^=second-level-]').each(function()  // iterate through each element which has class starts with 'second-level-'
    {     
       if(!$(this).attr("class").contains(this_class)) 
           $(this).hide();
       else
           $(this).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/1jgo6mpc/1/

`UPDATE :` In order to avoid hardcoding of every target class in the selector, you can append an additional class with same name ( in the example below I have added class 'target' ) to each li tag.

```
<nav id="main-nav">
<ul class="main-nav-level1">
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img class="abc-logo" src="images/abc-Logo.png" alt="abc logo" title="abc logo"/></a></li>
<li class="target vehicles level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Vehicles</a></li>
<li class="target shop level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Shop</a></li>
<li class="target finance level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Finance</a></li>
<li class="target owner level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Owner</a></li>
<li class="locate-dealer-link level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img class="signin-avatar" src="images/mobile_locate_icon.PNG" alt="locate a dealer" title="locate a dealer"/>Locate a dealer</a></li>
<li class="level1"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img class="signin-avatar" src="images/icon-search.png" alt="Search" title="Search"/></a></li></ul>
 <div class="second-level-vehicles level1-child">
 <ul class="second-level-vehicles-nav">
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Popular</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Cars</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">SUV &amp; Crossovers</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Trucks &amp; Vans</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Commercial Vehicles</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Future Vehicles</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
 <table class="second-level-shop level1-child"  cellpadding="15">
 <tr>
 <th>Research</th>
 <th>Shop</th>
 <th>Buy</th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Build &amp; Price</a></td>
 <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Search Dealer Inventory</a></td>
 <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Request a Quote</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Help me Choose</a></td>
 <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Special Offers</a></td>
 <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Estimate your Payment</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Brochures and Guides</a></td>
 <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Schedule a Test Drive</a></td>
 <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Trade-in Value</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Get Updates</a></td>
 <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Certified Pre-Owned</a></td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
 </nav>


<script>
    $().ready(function(){
  $(".target").click(function(){
    var this_class = $(this).attr("class").split(' ')[1];
    $('[class^=second-level-]').each(function()
    {     
       if(!$(this).attr("class").contains(this_class))
           $(this).hide();
       else
        $(this).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
});


</script>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/1jgo6mpc/2/

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am still not able to hide other elements. Also, is it possible to avoid he class names .vehicles, .shop and others because right now I am just preparing the UI but in reality the number of li's populated can be dynamic. Is it possible that I can assign a common class name to all the li's like level1. ?

Comment: updated the solution and example to do so. check it out and see if that works

Comment: Just tried but it is throwing this error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr(...).contains is not a function"

Comment: in the fiddle or in your solution ?

Comment: In my solution. Is there anything else you want me to provide you ?

Comment: Check the jquery references. Also make sure the jquery version is 1.4 or higher

Comment: I am using jquery 2.2 but still getting the same error.

Comment: Just an update. Clearing the browser cache helped. Thanks. One more query. Is there any way I can get rid of hard coding the class names ".vehicles,.shop,.finance,.owner" in line 2. Since they will be dynamic.

Comment: Updated the solution for your last question. Follow the section 'Update'

Comment: Thanks for the updates and everything looks fine but one thing. When I click on the Vehicles in line 4. The Menu toggles for a moment and then disappears again and leaves behind just partial div "second-level-vehicles" that leaves the effect as if it is a gray underline. Rest of the menu items are working fine. If need be I can provide the whole code in case you want to recreate the scenario. Thanks again.